# getting old data-attribute value on clicking updated anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding a function **`addToCart`** on clicking a swatch (which is anchor) but when i click on the size it's adding items to cart with old IDs. Code snippet which i have written so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product-tile').on('click', '.product-swatches .swatch-list li a.swatch', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedVariantObject = $(this).data('allvariations');
        var selectedVariantIDList = Object.keys(selectedVariantObject);
        // Check if all variants are not available show the Sold Out message 

        var $parentHeaderArea = $(this).parents('.product-tile');
        var $allAnchors = $parentHeaderArea.find('li a.swatchanchor');
        for (var anchorIndex=0; anchorIndex < $allAnchors.length; anchorIndex++) {
            var elementObj = $allAnchors[anchorIndex];
            var $elem = $(elementObj).closest('li');
            
            var variantIdToAssign = selectedVariantIDList[anchorIndex]
            elementObj.setAttribute('data-pidval', variantIdToAssign)
            
            var variantStatus = selectedVariantObject[variantIdToAssign];
            //var hasUnSelectableClass = $($elem).hasClass('unselectable');
            
            if ((variantStatus == true)) {
                $elem.removeClass('unselectable');
                $elem.addClass('selectable');
                elementObj.onclick = addToCartCLP;
            } else {
                $elem.removeClass('selectable');
                $elem.addClass('unselectable');                
            }   
        }

        var btnStatus = $(this).data('btnstatus')
        var $textTagElement = $(this).closest('.product-tile').find('.btn-overlay .text-tag');
        if (btnStatus == 'OOS') {
            $textTagElement.html('Sold Out');
        } else {
            $textTagElement.html('Add to Cart');    
        }
    });

    $('.btn-overlay .swatches li.selectable').on('click', 'a.swatchanchor', addToCartCLP);

});
```

In above function, 1st I am updating the data attribute `data-pidvalue` and after that when i click on that anchor tag the binded function is getting old values? Can somebody suggest me a better solution?

**Note: **Initial binding is done by this line of code:

```
$('.btn-overlay .swatches li.selectable').on('click', 'a.swatchanchor', addToCartCLP);
```

**EDITED**

```
var addToCartCLP = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchorTag = $(this);
    var $pid = anchorTag.data('pidval');
    addItemToCartCLP($pid).then(function (response) {
        $.ajax({url: Urls.cartABUrl,
            success: function(){

            }});
        minicart.show(response);
//        showPopupAddedToBag(false);
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: Where are you reading the value of `data-pidval`?

Comment: in addToCart and there is on AJAX

Comment: How are you reading it? Are you using `.attr('data-pidval')` or `.data('pidval')`? You need to put all the relevant code in the question.

Comment: I have updated the question. Answer to your question, I am using .data('pidval')

Comment: You have to be consistent. If you use `.data()` to read it, you have to use `.data()` to save it.